# trying to set config value `IHostBuilder` but not reflected for ConfigureServices in Startup class - asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I have below config with empty connection string,

```
"ConnString": {
"Value":  "" 
},
```

Now in Asp.Net Core 3.1 app I am trying to set the connection string value inside `CreateHostBuilder`

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                {
                    var settings = config.Build();
                    settings["ConnString:Value"] = "MY CONNECTION STRING";

                });

                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

But this value is NOT reflected in `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup` class, it is still showing empty. What should I need to do here? please suggest!

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var updateValue = Configuration.GetSection("ConnString:Value").Value;
    }
```

Comment: Try using `Configuration["ConnString:Value"]`. FYI, for connection strings, asp.net provides helpers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#connection-string-prefixes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are building the configuration and setting the value on the **new** `IConfiguration` object. However these settings will be lost as you aren't setting the values on the *builder*. The underlying infrastructure calls **Build** again later which creates another **new** `IConfiguration`. The values don't magically transfer over.

What you can do instead is call [`AddInMemoryCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.memoryconfigurationbuilderextensions.addinmemorycollection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_MemoryConfigurationBuilderExtensions_AddInMemoryCollection_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfigurationBuilder_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Collections_Generic_KeyValuePair_System_String_System_String___) and pass your new settings there. This will then get consumed by the infrastructure and be made available later (ie in `ConfigureServices`):

```
webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
{
   config.AddInMemoryCollection(
     new [] { 
       new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ConnString:Value", "MY CONNECTION STRING") 
     }
   );
});
```

`IWebHostBuilder` also has a [`UseSetting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostbuilder.usesetting?view=aspnetcore-3.1) method where you can configure a *single* setting. This adds a new in-memory configuration provider containing just one value:

```
webBuilder.UseSetting("ConnString:Value", "MY CONNECTION STRING");
```

Note that the `IWebHostBuilder` will consume the configuration from the `IHostBuilder` (the generic host). You could alternatively call `ConfigureAppConfiguration` on the host builder instead.

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) 
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
     {
        config.AddInMemoryCollection(
          new [] { 
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ConnString:Value", "MY CONNECTION STRING") 
          }
        );
     });
```

This "injection" is particularly useful if you have settings that are used to configure *other* settings. You could instead add them in `ConfigureHostConfiguration` (which doesn't exist for `IWebHostBuilder`) allowing their values to be available *within* `ConfigureAppConfiguration` on either builder.

Note that the configuration isn't shared *back* to the host builder. Any configuration you add to the web host doesn't automatically apply to the generic host. I call this out because it is different from the behavior of the `ServiceCollection` which is shared between the two (adding services to one adds to the other).

**Update** based on your comments:

I mentioned above that [`ConfigureHostConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuilder.configurehostconfiguration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) can be used if you have settings used to configure/setup other configuration providers. This is particularly useful for something like configuring Azure KeyVault.

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) 
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
     {
        // setup bootstrapping settings. For example if we need to add in values used
        // to configure azure key vault stored in app settings and maybe some in memory 
        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        config.AddInMemoryCollection(
          new [] { 
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ClientId", "AzureClientId"), 
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TenantId", "AzureTenantId") 
          }
        );
     })
     // settings added in ConfigureHostConfiguration are now available via context.Configuration
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
     {
         // use the values we added during bootstrapping 
         var tenant = context.Configuration["TenantId"];
         var client = context.Configuration["ClientId"];
         // example, I don't remember the parameters off-hand
         config.AddAzureKeyVault(tenant, client, /*etc*/);
     });
```

In this example `ConfigureAppConfiguration` could also be called on the `IWebHostBuilder` instead.

For more information about configuration and the generic host, [see the](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#host-configuration) [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#app-configuration).

Comment: thanks, actually I am getting something `clientSecret` from azure key vault and something I saw `webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                    {
                        var settings = config.Build();
                        settings.AddSecretClient();
                    });`

Comment: how to add `AddSecretClient()` and I asked question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62634744/how-to-set-the-values-for-azureadclientsecret-before-sending-to-the-addwebapp

Comment: Could you please suggest something there?

Comment: Yes. Configure it in the generic host's `ConfigureHostConfiguration`

Comment: Thanks a lot @ pinkfloydx33